# Double iteration in list of tuples of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to ask how can I get the same output but by applying a double list comprehension.
Thank you.

```
a = [(('123',),('a',)),(('456',),('b',)),(('789',),('c',))]

b = [i[0] for i in a]

c = [i[0] for i in b]
```

output:

```
['123', '456', '789']
```

Comment: Why not just `[i[0][0] for i in a]`? Or, if you really want a double list comprehension, `[i[0] for i in [j[0] for j in a]]`.

Comment: Thank you @rassar. That was incredibly fast. Still a beginner in Python. Hope this helps other beginners.

Comment: Thank you for the editting @Wondercricket. Still a beginner on Stackoverflow posting as well.

Comment: @rassar Add it as an answer because it will be hard for users to find an answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Ch3steR, adding @rassar's comment as answer.

Why not just [i[0][0] for i in a]? Or, if you really want a double list comprehension, [i[0] for i in [j[0] for j in a]].